# Testing for whether geometries include other when touching borders in R

Tags: r, maps, gis, polygon, r-sf

I am new to geodata so maybe this is a silly question.
I have two multipolygons and what I want to do is to test in which of the polygon of "constituencies" each polygon of "wards" is contained. Basically, to see for each ward in which consituency it is in.

However, I am having issues with the function `st_within()` from `sf` because it only returns TRUE if the first geometry is *completely* within the second geometry. That is a problem when the smaller units touch the borders of the larger ones. Here is an example

I have one multipolygon called "consituencies" and and one called "wards". You can find them here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xu08wm79rym00zz/AADFDpyPe0EuDSDSY-6SvqpYa?dl=0

There's 2 objects in constituencies:

```
plot(constituencies$geometry)
```

[image]
I then try to join them on whether the wards are *within* the constituencies

```
wards <- st_transform(wards, crs = st_crs(constituencies))
test98 <- st_join(wards, constituencies, join=st_within)
```

And the outcome spits out many NAs on the constituencies' name and label a ward is within of.

```
    head(test98)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 531936.6 ymin: 180569.5 xmax: 533595.1 ymax: 182082.5
projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
  WD98CD       WD98NM                             name label                       geometry
1 00AAFA   Aldersgate                             <NA>  <NA> MULTIPOLYGON (((532104.9 18...
2 00AAFB      Aldgate                             <NA>  <NA> MULTIPOLYGON (((533319.2 18...
3 00AAFC    Bassishaw Cities of London and Westminster   107 MULTIPOLYGON (((532587.3 18...
4 00AAFD Billingsgate Cities of London and Westminster   107 MULTIPOLYGON (((533167.9 18...
5 00AAFE  Bishopsgate                             <NA>  <NA> MULTIPOLYGON (((533410.7 18...
6 00AAFF Bread Street Cities of London and Westminster   107 MULTIPOLYGON (((532300.3 18...
```

When I plot them to see which ones have NA in name (in red), you can see it is the ones touching the consituency's borders:

```
plot(constituencies_short$geometry)
plot(test98$geometry[!is.na(test98$name),], col = "green", add = T)
plot(test98$geometry[is.na(test98$name),], col = "red", add = T)
```

[image]

I assume one of two things is happening: 1) touching borders dos not count as being completely within a geometry, or 2) the borders of the wards and constituencies may not be perfectly matched so the wards aren't entirely within the constituency.

My question is: is there a way of perfectly match the borders and then test which wards are within which constituencies OR is there a way of testing within which constituencies is not the entirety but the majority of a ward's boundaries?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, great question! Unfortunately, I can't open your datasets. One line of your code jumps out to me: `st_crs(wards) == st_crs(constituencies)` This is usually a bad idea because it simply overwrites the CRS. Try `st_transform(wards, st_crs(constituencies)` instead!

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Will correct it. Shame about the link, can't understand why that is. Can you maybe try this instead: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zHON4DdtvnTkEPoVia0WFfEXIo0Wm_Il?usp=sharing ?

Comment: I can load those, but here it seems the CRS are the same (but the geometry is slightly off). Did you manipulate the CRS here already? Also I was mistaken in my previous comment: Your line of code does not change the CRS, it simply tests if they are equal. The expression is `TRUE`  for me using your datasts.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I ran "wards <- st_transform(wards, crs = st_crs(constituencies))" and then updated it in the link. I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: Can you provide samples of the unaltered datasets? Also, any information of where they came from (which CRS was used) would be useful to try to align them properly.

Comment: Of course. Here are samples from the unaltered dataset: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cSx8TpvXn0z2JoUijSKiBM-RuXBgRCuu?usp=sharing
They both say "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid" as their CRS, the constituencies have EPSG: 27700 and wards is NA. These are all from Offical Statistics records in the UK.

Comment: It is not an issue with the CRS as I thought after all. The geometries look off more dramatically because half the river is included in the constitiuencies.

Answer (score 4):

Your boundaries do not align exactly. Let's see what happens when we intersect the first ward with the two constituencies:

```
> st_intersection(wards$geom[1], constituencies$geom)
Geometry set for 2 features 
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 531936.6 ymin: 181262.6 xmax: 532309 ymax: 182012
projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
POLYGON ((532104.9 182011.9, 532126.3 181948, 5...
MULTIPOLYGON (((532022.4 181893.5, 532022.4 181...
```

we get two output features because the ward has some of it in both constituencies. How much? Let's see:

```
> st_area(st_intersection(wards$geom[1], constituencies$geom))
Units: [m^2]
[1] 1.298829e+05 9.542473e-01
```

So that's 129882m^2 in one and 0.95m^2 in the other. Your boundaries misalign so that there's 1 square metre of the ward in the "wrong" constituency!

A fix would be to compute the areas of the full intersection set and threshold on a value or proportion of the ward area.

You can use `st_intersects` to get a list of all overlaps:

```
> st_intersects(wards, constituencies)

Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 25, where the predicate was `intersects'
first 10 elements:
 1: 1, 2
 2: 1
 3: 1
 4: 1
 5: 1, 2
 6: 1
```

Any elements of that list with one element are wards that overlap one and only one constituency, otherwise you need to compute the area proportions of the overlap of that ward with those constituencies to work out which ones the ward is mostly over.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful! However, I am back at the same issue, right? Using sf_intersects gives me *every* single intersection and not the constituency in which the larger part of a ward's geometry is in. Could you just pls provide an example code of how I would "need to compute the area proportions of the overlap of that ward with those constituencies to work out which ones the ward is mostly over"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I don't have time to write complete solutions, and I left it at a place where someone with some R programming should be able to finish the job. Loop `i` over the output of the `st_intersects`, compute `st_area` of ward `i` and the constituencies in `i-th` intersection list element, make a decision as to which to take.

Comment: fair enough, I'm sorry! I'm still quite new to all of this and didn't want to make any inappropriate question.  It was just to make sure I understood and to get the full answer in here for others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since we are dealing with only slight differences, one approach would be to create a slight negative / inset buffer around the wards geometries before joining.

#### Prep

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

wards_transformed <- st_transform(wards, st_crs(constituencies))
```

### Without buffer:

```
wards_transformed %>%
  st_join(constituencies, st_within)
```

[image: Result (no buffer)]

### With negative buffer:

```
wards_transformed %>%
  st_buffer(-10) %>%
  st_join(constituencies, st_within)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much! It does the trick in the example I put in here but in the full dataset I still get a lot of NAs, probably because the differences there might be larger in some way or because there might another problem.

Comment: If you want to share some edge cases, I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Really? Thank you so much! That's really nice of you. You can find the two full datasets here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1igXVUaVVCyheERL8m-SGDg71-8GnnBuf?usp=sharing

Comment: With edge cases i meant some example geometries that will not work with this approach or that might point to another problem.